# How to remove php7 completely from centos 6?

Tags: centos, package-management, php, mediawiki

I was trying to build a wiki on centos server and I downloaded PHP7 from its official website. When I wanted to remove it, I found that even if I deleted all the PHP7 files(I install it using a tar.gz), I can still get this:

```
[root@xxx ~]# php -v
PHP 7.1.0 (cli) (built: Jan 15 2017 19:41:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

After I installed the PHP5 using yum I found that the version of PHP was still 7. I tried to uninstalled PHP5 and after that, the situation was same. Can anybody help me to remove PHP7 totally?